# how does the dp solution cover all subarray sums?

Tags: python

I can't understand the dp solution to problem 'find sub array with max sum of its elements'

The dynamic programming solution:

```
def f(nums):
  for i in range(1, len(nums)):        
    nums[i] = max(nums[i], nums[i] + nums[i - 1])

  return max(nums)

a = [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]

f(a)
```

the subarray with max sum of elements is `[4,-1,2,1]`, the sum of this subarray is 6.

How does the dp solution above calculate  the exact sum of this subarray `[4,-1,2,1]`?

I made my own solution, which is kinda brute force - it's 2 loops, it goes from start to end , but increases start index and it prints all subarrays.

I dont understand how the dp solution covers that `[4,-1,2,1]` subarray!

my solution prints all subarrays:

```
[]
[-2]
[-2, 1]
[-2, 1, -3]
[-2, 1, -3, 4]
[-2, 1, -3, 4, -1]
[-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2]
[-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1]
[-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5]
-------------------------------------
[]
[1]
[1, -3]
[1, -3, 4]
[1, -3, 4, -1]
[1, -3, 4, -1, 2]
[1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1]
[1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5]
-------------------------------------
[]
[-3]
[-3, 4]
[-3, 4, -1]
[-3, 4, -1, 2]
[-3, 4, -1, 2, 1]
[-3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5]
-------------------------------------
[]
[4]
[4, -1]
[4, -1, 2]
[4, -1, 2, 1]
[4, -1, 2, 1, -5]
-------------------------------------
[]
[-1]
[-1, 2]
[-1, 2, 1]
[-1, 2, 1, -5]
-------------------------------------
[]
[2]
[2, 1]
[2, 1, -5]
-------------------------------------
[]
[1]
[1, -5]
-------------------------------------
[]
[-5]
```

my brute force solution:

```
import math
def f(nums):
    local_sum = 0
    global_sum = float('-inf')
    print(nums)

    res = []
    for r in range(len(nums)):
        print('-------------------------------------')
        before = 0
        for i in range(r,len(nums)):
            print(nums[r:i])

            local_sum = nums[i] + before
            before = local_sum
            if local_sum > global_sum:
                global_sum = local_sum        
        res.append(global_sum)
    print(max(res))
    return max(res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my humble opinion, the first thing to understand where trying/doing a `dp` solution to a problem is to understand what does `dp[i]` means. In this case you can raise that question: **What does `dp[i]` means?** And by looking at the code you can see that (i will rename `dp` as `nums`) in your code:

```
nums[i] = max(nums[i], nums[i] + nums[i - 1])
```

So, you are storing in `nums[i]` the maximum value between what was in position `i` and the sum the value of position `i` with the value of position `i-1`. So, one way `nums[i]` value is bigger then leave it at that. On the other hand that means, adding the next value will increase the sum, so change it. When the next step of the loop is performed you would have at `i` the sum of the latest subarray sum so you do the that for the rest of the array.

So, What is the answer to the question?

> At `dp[i]` you have the value of the maximum subarray sum that ends at position `i`

So, from there you just select the maximum value of that array.

**Note:** This solution does that in place so `nums` is modified. You would have to do something to get the subarray.