# Can anyone explain this "Maxium Subarray" problem?

Tags: python

I once saw this coding question online..

> Given an integer array nums, find the contiguous subarray (containing
>   at least one number) which has the largest sum and return its sum. 
>   Example:

```
Input: [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4],
Output: 6
Explanation: [4,-1,2,1] has the largest sum = 6.
```

...and got a solution from a leetcode user...

```
def maxSubArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    sumVal = 0
    ret = 0
    for i in nums:
        sumVal = max(0, sumVal) + i
        ret = max(ret, sumVal)
    return max(nums) if ret == 0 else ret
```

Though I don't know how it works even after some "debugging".

Can you explain it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86CQq3pKSUw

Comment: This is not that exact code, but maybe this will help: [Largest-sum-contiguous-subarray](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/), also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60889421/how-does-the-dp-solution-cover-all-subarray-sums/60890922#60890922) solving that problem with dynamic programming.

Comment: Do see my answer and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question states all its asking for is to find the maximum value that's possible in the subarray using contiguous elements,i.e. adjacent elements.

The approach here is to go through the array one by one and add the elements to the total sum and check if it exceeds the current max value and if so, update the max value. See inline comments on what each line does.

```
def maxSubArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> int: #type hint to return an int value
    sumVal = 0 #keeps the total sum
    ret = 0 #return value
    for i in nums: #iterates through every single value in the list
        sumVal = max(0, sumVal) + i #gets the total sum for the upto the given i value
        ret = max(ret, sumVal) #ret variable is updated with whichever is the max of `ret` or `sumVal`.
    return max(nums) if ret == 0 else ret #retunrs max value of the array if ret = 0; this simply means array is of single element.Else return the value held in `ret`
```

**This code though is not complete.** It doesnt attempt to check for the contigous values but simply the possible sums.

Running this,

```
def maxSubArray(nums):
    sumVal = 0
    ret = 0
    for i in nums:
        sumVal = max(0, sumVal) + i
        ret = max(ret, sumVal)
    return max(nums) if ret == 0 else ret

print(maxSubArray([8,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]))
```

Gives `12`. See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/) to learn more on this

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the subarray `[8,1,-3,4,-1,2,1]` yields a sum of 12 and it looks pretty correct.

Comment: Good find; I got mixed up with another logic. Updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
The maximum-subarray problem: it takes as input an array of numbers, and it determines the contiguous subarray whose values have the greatest sum.

    /***************************************************************************************************************************
    *****************************************Maximum SubArray Problem***********************************************************
    ****************************************************************************************************************************
Example:
----------
Day 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
Price 100 113 110 85 105 102 86 63 81 101 94 106 101 79 94 90 97
Change 13 -3 -25 20 -3 -16 -23 18 20 -7 12 -5 -22 15 -4 7

      /\
     /  \
    /    \
     |  |
     |  |

Information about the price of stock in the Volatile Chemical Corporation after the close
of trading over a period of 17 days. The horizontal axis of the chart indicates the day, and the vertical
axis shows the price. The bottom row of the table gives the change in price from the previous day.
 


Day 01 23 4
Price 10 11 7 10 6
Change 1 -4 3 -4
      /\
     /  \
    /    \
     |  |
     |  |
An example showing that the maximum profit does not always start at the lowest price
or end at the highest price. Again, the horizontal axis indicates the day, and the vertical axis shows
the price. Here, the maximum profit of $3 per share would be earned by buying after day 2 and
selling after day 3. The price of $7 after day 2 is not the lowest price overall, and the price of $10
after day 3 is not the highest price overall.


A brute-force solution
We can easily devise a brute-force solution to this problem: just try every possible
pair of buy and sell dates in which the buy date precedes the sell date. A period of n
days has (n/2) such pairs of dates. Since n/2
is (Θ)n2 and the best we can hope for
is to evaluate each pair of dates in constant time, this approach would take Ω(n2)
time.  We Can do better.

Let’s think about how we might solve the maximum-subarray problem using
the divide-and-conquer technique. Suppose we want to find a maximum subarray of the subarray A[Low to High]
Divide-and-conquer suggests that we divide
the subarray into two subarrays of as equal size as possible.That is, we find
the midpoint, say mid, of the subarray, and consider the subarrays A[Low to mid] A[mid+1 to high] 
any contiguous subarray A[i..j]
of A[Low to High] must lie in exactly one of the following places
entirely in the subarray : A[Low to mid] so that low<= i <= j <= mid
entirely in the subarray: A[mid+1 to high] so that mid<= i <= j <= high
crossing the midpoint, so that low <= i <= mid < j <= high.

We are considering crossing the midpoint becuase there is chance that our max arry must be crosing the mid point in above exmaple max array will be 18 20 -7 12
 from inde 7 to index 10
 
    */
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    struct result
    {
        int m_left;
        int m_right;
        int m_LeftRightSum;
        void print()
        {
            cout<<"leftIndex:"<<m_left<<endl;
            cout<<"rightIndex:"<<m_right<<endl;
            cout<<"sum:"<<m_LeftRightSum<<endl;
        }
    };
    result maxCrossSubArray(int arr[], int low, int mid, int high);
    result maxSubArray(int arr[], int low, int high);
    
    result maxCrossSubArray(int arr[], int low, int mid, int high)
    {
        result obj;
        int leftSum = INT_MIN;
        int sum = 0;
        int maxLeft,maxRight;
        for(int i=mid;i>=low;i--)
        {
            sum +=arr[i];
            if(sum>leftSum)
            {
                leftSum = sum;
                maxLeft = i;
            }
        }
        sum = 0;
        int rightSum=INT_MIN;
        for(int j=mid+1;j<=high;j++)
        {
            sum +=arr[j];
            if(sum>rightSum)
            {
                rightSum = sum;
                maxRight = j;
            }
    
        }
        obj.m_left = maxLeft;
        obj.m_right = maxRight;
        obj.m_LeftRightSum = leftSum + rightSum;
        //obj.print();
        return obj;
    }
    result maxSubArray(int arr[], int low, int high)
    {
        result objLeft,objRight,objCross;
        if(high == low)
        {
            result obj;
            obj.m_left = low;
            obj.m_right = high;
            obj.m_LeftRightSum = arr[low];
            return obj;
        }
        else
        {
            int mid = (low + high)/2;
            objLeft =  maxSubArray(arr,low,mid);
            objRight = maxSubArray(arr,mid+1,high);
            objCross = maxCrossSubArray(arr,low,mid,high);
        }
        if(objLeft.m_LeftRightSum >= objRight.m_LeftRightSum &&  objLeft.m_LeftRightSum >= objCross.m_LeftRightSum)
            return objLeft;
        else if(objRight.m_LeftRightSum >= objLeft.m_LeftRightSum &&  objRight.m_LeftRightSum >= objCross.m_LeftRightSum)
            return objRight;
        else
            return objCross;
    
    }
    int main()
    {
        
        int arr[] = { { 13,-3,-25,20,-3,-16,-23,18,20,-7,12,-5,-22,15,-4,7};};
        for(auto i : arr)
            cout<<i<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])<<endl;
        result obj = maxSubArray(arr,0,8);
    
        cout<<"Maximum sub array will be from:"<<obj.m_left<<" to:  "<<obj.m_right<<" and sum is:"<<obj.m_LeftRightSum<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Divide-and-conquer suggests that we divide the subarray into two subarrays of as equal size as possible. That is, we find the midpoint, say mid, of the subarray, and consider the subarrays A[Low to mid] A[mid+1 to high] 
any contiguous subarray A[i..j]
of A[Low to High] must lie in exactly one of the following places
entirely in the subarray : A[Low to mid] so that low<= i <= j <= mid
entirely in the subarray: A[mid+1 to high] so that mid<= i <= j <= high
crossing the midpoint, so that low <= i <= mid < j <= high.

Comment: The explanation should be in your _answer_, not a comment. Again, please read [answer].

Comment: Edited the answer with description. Please revisit

Comment: The description you added is hidden at the bottom of a code block. It requires the user to hunt for it and then scroll sideways to read. Code belongs in a code block, but prose doesn't. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Correctly formatted and I think we'll described answer And will above mentioned  other codes work for the finding a max subarray crossing the mid of array